# How do I display a property in the viewport without using a modal operator?

Tags: python, scripting

I want to display a property in the viewport without using a modal operator. is it possible? I found [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31908/draw-and-update-text-in-viewport-without-modal-operator-in-blender), but I did not understand how I can use (I started with python).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Extending the code from [Draw and update text in viewport without modal operator in blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/31908/draw-and-update-text-in-viewport-without-modal-operator-in-blender)

I suggest using a class to handle the handles, and pass `context` to the callback method.

```
import bpy
import blf

class DrawingClass:
    def __init__(self, context, prop):
        self.prop = prop
        self.handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(
                   self.draw_text_callback,(context,),
                   'WINDOW', 'POST_PIXEL')

    def draw_text_callback(self, context):
        font_id = 0  # XXX, need to find out how best to get this.

        # draw some text
        blf.position(font_id, 15, 50, 0)
        blf.size(font_id, 20, 72)
        blf.draw(font_id, "%s %s" % (context.scene.name, self.prop))



    def remove_handle(self):
         bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_remove(self.handle, 'WINDOW')

context = bpy.context             
dc = DrawingClass(context, "Draw This On Screen")

#dc.remove_handle()  # will remove the handle and stop drawing
```

Comment: to handle the handles, from now on I shall use this on my colleagues :D

Comment: Nice approach, but how we can store the reference to the class in order to remove the handle at later time e.g. based on a scene property enabled or disabled by the user?

Comment: Give it global scope to update method of some scene property, or what I find a bulletproof "hack"  `bpy.app.driver_namespace["foo"] = bar`

Comment: Sorry, wasn't notified @batFINGER. Updating a scene property requires another static variable in the class which ends up in a mess referencing static variables. I really like your idea, in theory it's super nice but in a real scenario for a addon or something, it does not really help IMHO. Maybe I'm too stupid. Anyway thanks for your hacky batTRICK!