# Draw floating UILayout

Tags: python

In sculpt mode you get this menu with a right click:

[image]

The UI elements in this menu are visually the same you would get by drawing a UI using [bpy.types.UILayout](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html) functions.
Yet, the only answers I found for drawing custom floating UI elements referred to [bgl](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bgl.html) and [blf](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/blf.html), like in these two Blender StackExchange questions:

1. [How to draw shapes in the node editor with python bgl](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57709/how-to-draw-shapes-in-the-node-editor-with-python-bgl#57786)
2. [Floating UI window in 3D view](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/44065/floating-ui-window-in-3d-view)

However, ideally I would use standard Blender UI elements to create something like that.
Is there a way to draw standard Blender UI elements in floating windows like those in the screenshot using Python?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [`WindowManager.invoke_props_popup(operator, event)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html?highlight=confirm#bpy.types.WindowManager.invoke_props_popup)

> Operator popup invoke (show operator properties and execute it automatically on changes)

Code based on [**How to call a confirmation dialog box?**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73548/31447), I just  replaced `invoke_props_dialog` by `invoke_props_popup` to diplay the popup without confirmation option:

[image]

```
import bpy

class SimplePropConfirmOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Really?"""
    bl_idname = "my_category.custom_confirm_dialog"
    bl_label = "Do you really want to do that?"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    prop1: bpy.props.BoolProperty()
    prop2: bpy.props.BoolProperty()

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "YES!")
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_popup(self, event)

    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout
        row.prop(self, "prop1", text="Property A")
        row.prop(self, "prop2", text="Property B")


class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator(SimplePropConfirmOperator.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimplePropConfirmOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimplePropConfirmOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: That's exactly it. Thanks! I was hoping to get more control over it, like setting it's position and the mouse distance to make it disappear though. But it's already great to have it working as in your example.

Comment: Cool. Unfortunately, there is nothing else you can do... in order to 'get more control', you can [set the cursor before calling `inkoke_props_popup()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Window.html?highlight=warp#bpy.types.Window.cursor_warp), that's it @narranoid