# Preselection highlight object?

Tags: python

iam currently creating a GUI for a kind of "rig" in the 3D Viewport **(Not in the Blender Game Engine!)**
and it would be an treat for the eyes to have highlighting while hovering over a button.

So how it should work:

How the "Button" (A Plane with an Text-Object) looks:
[image: Picture of a Plane with Text on it]

How it should look when you point with the mouse on it:
[image: Same picture as before but with a mouse ontop it and the "Button" changed the color]

If this gets too complicated please tell me :)

Have a nice day!

Comment: I don't understand your question at all :(

Comment: imma edit it to make it more clear sorry :(

Comment: He asks for a mouse over effect for the buttons. I fear that this is not possible with the current Blender UI.

Comment: i edited it, hope its more clear now.

Comment: Wait, are we talking about the BGE? Then this youtube tutorial might help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klcDrW7xmwo

Comment: Not about the bge, Like i said about the 3D Viewport :)

Comment: Yes, and here you have to go across the game engine python code :)

Comment: Have a [look at this answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41329/935).

Comment: Thanks sambler thats exactly the result iam aiming for, but sadly i dont understand anything of this code and cant really use it :/

Comment: i think this'd be easier to create with mesh objects, but i dunno how to check if the mouse is over it.

Comment: Can you check if the mouse is over a mesh object?