# Viewport widgets with draw handler

Tags: python, operator, opengl

Is it possible to create viewport widgets with draw handler?

I have an operator which produces simple mesh geometry, I use operator redo properties panel to edit the result as shown in animation below:

[image: operator props]

But I want to draw on-screen property widgets in the viewport, like so:

[image: 2d widgets]

Would this kind of functionality be possible using modal operator and draw handler?

Also is it possible to create 3D widgets similar way?

[image: 3d widgets]

Comment: These addons can draw some additional UI in the viewport, though they are not interactive I think. Maybe exploring their source code will help you attain what you need https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?407260-AddOn-NP-Point-Copy

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thanks, I already looked into various add-ons, and the only add-on that might hold the answer is Motion Trails, but it's 2k lines of badly structured code, I doubt I can make sense of it.

Comment: [Somewhat Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41329/15543) in that it uses bgl to overdraw 3d views when mousing over the simple rectangular "button".  However it is my belief that bgl is going to be dropped from 2.8.

Comment: @batFINGER thatnks! This is is actually what I was looking for! I already made code that creates working slider, and this code add's region detection to it.