# Make Bgl 2d drawing coordinates stay relative to viewport

Tags: python, opengl

So i drew a 2d polygon and some blf text using a modal operator. But a problem arised. The 2d shape and text wouldnt stay relavant to the screen size of the 3d viewport. I would seem as if the vertex coordinates are static to the screen coordinates and not to the 3d viewport. As you can see in the gif that dragging the screen completely hides the drawing. so my question is,

## How do i make the 2d drawing coordinates stay relative to the 3d viewport so that resizing the window doesnt hide the 2d drawing ?

[image]

The code:-

```
def draw_poly(points):
  for i in range(len(points)):
        bgl.glVertex2f(points[i][0],points[i][1])

def draw_callback_px(self, context):
  panel_points = [[10.0, 550.0],  #[x, y]
                 [10.0, 685.0],  #[x, y]
                 [150.0, 685.0], #[x, y]
                 [150.0, 550.0], #[x, y]
                 [120, 500],
                 [80, 490],
                 [40, 500],
                 ]

# draw poly
  bgl.glColor4f(1.0, 0.085, 0.0, 0.2)
  bgl.glEnable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
  bgl.glBegin(bgl.GL_POLYGON)
  draw_poly(panel_points)
  bgl.glEnd()

# draw outline
  bgl.glColor4f(0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 1.0)
  bgl.glLineWidth(4)
  bgl.glBegin(bgl.GL_LINE_LOOP)
  draw_poly(panel_points)
  bgl.glEnd()

  font_id = 0
# draw some text
  bgl.glColor4f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 0.8)
  blf.position(font_id, 15, 620, 0)
  blf.size(font_id, 50, 100)
  blf.draw(font_id, "BGL")

  blf.position(font_id, 15, 580, 0)
  blf.size(font_id, 30, 100)
  blf.draw(font_id, "Widget")

# restore opengl defaults
  bgl.glLineWidth(1)
  bgl.glDisable(bgl.GL_BLEND)
  bgl.glColor4f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
```

Comment: Look at example pointed out [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92955/draw-a-2d-box-using-bgl-in-viewport#comment164315_92956)

Comment: If anything is static in example above it's your coordinates.  The screen has a resolution of how many pixels by pixels.  Each area region has a width and height in pixels  The origin is the bottom left corner. If you statically draw a "widget" at y=550 do you expect to see it when the area height is less than 550?   Have a nice day.

Comment: That's why I asked the question, I want the widget to be relative to the window size and move or resize dynamically every time the window is resized. I am completely lost here because of the lack of documentation.

Comment: Doubt it's the lack of docs that has you lost. Do you really need documentation to scale  into a region `context.region.width` by `context.region.height` ?  [I understand what you *want*, here is your last question on this I answered](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92955/draw-a-2d-box-using-bgl-in-viewport) .. what incentive do I have to answer another... some other kind soul on bse will I'm sure.