# How to add controls to 3D View using python?

Tags: python, 3d-view

I'm trying to draw a series of arrows on 3D view and let the user click and drag to change some properties on screen.

I want to draw objects to the 3D View using `bgl`, but how would I go into handling the mouse input on the 3D View?

Comment: Depending on what you are going for it's either really hard or probably impossible to achieve with the current version. I suggest have a look into [retopoflow addon](https://github.com/CGCookie/retopoflow) to get some inspiration. However, Blender 2.8 introduces [custom manipulators](https://developer.blender.org/T51844), although also pretty low level at its current state. Nice `bgl` answers at BSE: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/92956/31447 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/913/31447,  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57714/31447

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to keep going. Thank you!