# How to handle drawing with multiple views

Tags: python, scripting, opengl

I want to draw in the screen space of each ImageEditor. The drawing itself works pretty good, each space has its own draw handle registerd with the correct "view_to_region" functions passed along. So the correct transformations
already work.

The problem is that every call of the drawing code ends up in every space, which is not exactly what it want... maybe im just overlooking something super obvious.

So does anyone know how to do this?

I think an image illustrates the issue quite well:

[image: very evil problem]

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41329/15543)  Draws a box button on all 3d views, only expands on mouse over the context area.