# Global variable visibility during script/operator execution?

Tags: python, operator

I wanted to have some global variables in an addon.

But doing so, *some parts* of the script were not able to access these variables. I had an error message saying I can not use them as they are not initialized.

In this addon, I took some parts of code I have found [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40675/display-in-viewport-without-modal-operation/40676#40676), in order to draw on the 3D View. The draw callback of the 'DrawingClass' in this code is able to see these global variables.

But in the operator itself, it does not work.

I have found a workaround setting these variables as class variable of the operator. So... 'it works' (even if the code is not very nice, currently).

But why some execution contexts (the drawing callback) allow to use these globals and not some others (invoke or execute of an operator) ?

I don't put the code directly here, as it is a bit long. But here is the blend file :
[image]

The variables are "inactive" and "replaceMode" which can be found in the "grsOperator" class. The script simply replaces the G, R, S keys standard behavior by the corresponding manipulator. On the bottom left of the 3D view, you can click on a square in order to change the mode ("replaceMode") or disable the key interception ("inactive").

Comment: is there a reason why you want to use global variables? i'm only asking because scene properties for instance would allow for similar functionality, and in addition get saved with the blend file

Comment: @aliasguru, just because this tool options are not related to any object or scene. Yes I should use properties, and probably I should restructure the code in order to put the drawing callback inside the operator (or something like that). But why the variable accessibility changes ?

Comment: Declaring them as globals, eg `global inactive` will fix the not initialized error. Check out http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/41329/15543

Comment: @batFINGER, if I declare 'global inactive = False', syntax error. If I declare 'global inactive' then 'inactive = False', I still have the problem 'referenced before assignment'

Comment: @batFINGER, ok forget it.. I read some Python docs and now I understand what you meant. Thanks !

Comment: @batFINGER, any idea about the "why" (during the callback, global no needed but during the operator execution global is needed) ?

Comment: Possibly (not great at explaining this stuff) because of registration to bpy.types.   Maybe setting up a data or settings module for your globals could be the way to go.