# opengl text display of custom properties?

Tags: python, 3d-view, properties, opengl

I have a bunch of simple objects with custom properties, e.g. description, comments, etc. I would like to be able to be able to view this information somehow in the viewport attached per each object and toggable on and off.

I've looked into information about bgl and blf but I cannot find an example that works and shows this type of functionality.

Comment: [Related](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40676/15543)

Comment: thanks @batFINGER. How woudl one go about attaching this type of text to a specific object?