# How to lock an updating object to the screen using scripts (Blender 3.5)

Tags: python, scripting, objects, 3d-view

I wanted to create an object that automatically updates with scripts and displays on the screen in a fixed position in Blender viewport. Kind of like how 'Objectives' in the top right of the image below or the 'Activity bar' in the bottom left would work. I want it so that the particular object (e.g. the objectives) stays glued to the screen while everything else (e.g. the scene displayed in the image below) moves as normal with the viewport. Ideally, I would want to use python scripts to do all of this. I've tried searching extensively for this but haven't found a solution and I would appreciate any help!

[image: Image of video game made using Blender]

Comment: Please describe why you need this, and what purpose it serves. That would help immensely and my heaven lead to finding a solution you did not even have on the radar.

Comment: I want to display some information incoming from another source on the screen while being able to move around the rest of my Blender model. The purpose it serves is for demoing the model.

Comment: I recommend using Blenders draw function with which you can draw on the 3d interface. See the following questions: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40676/92700 https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/76020/92700 And the Font Drawing API reference: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/blf.html

Comment: Thank you! I will check it out.